# Current position in grant applications when unemployed

Tags: cv

I have recently completed a post-doc and am currently unemployed. However, I am doing the same activities as before, mostly writing and publishing papers that resulted from my postdoc. Obviously, I am not getting paid and am not under contract from my previous institution. I am also doing some freelance work, just a few hours a week, for a private company which is however not known in academic circles and is a very small company. So I don't see any large benefit in listing myself as a freelancer for such company. Just listing freelancer people might be wondering what kind of freelance and it would not make sense for academics.

**What are my options to show that I am still active in research and that it makes sense for academics reading my CV in a grant application?**

Should I list my current position as a "consultant" for my ex-institution? People know that there's not such thing in academia and might be wondering and why I am not a "post-doc".

Comment: I am curious to see what will the SE:academia world will answer. In real life it is totally acceptable to be unemployed and/or to have short spells working in totally unrelated areas: only rich people can dedicate themselves to the higher good of research and science as unpaid worker for their former professors/supervisors/departments.

Comment: You should not be working for free.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Completing one's own papers is not "working for free".

Comment: @lighthousekeeper It is if you're not getting paid for it.

Comment: Are you writing grant applications in order to be employed again by some university in case of success, or are you planning to continue the way it is now?

Comment: @Snijderfrey Obviously I am not rich :), I am writing papers and grants because I want to get a position.

Comment: In this case, I would say that having a strong supporting letter from an institution is more important than how exactly you call your current position.

Answer (score 2):

**Independent researcher**. Under this label, you can summarize the completion of your own papers from the previous job, and the consulting work.

Comment: I am not totally convinced, researcher financed by whom?

Comment: @HermanToothrot The word *independent* spins the fact that one does not have a main employment in a positive way.